# 400 Bad request error, it is saying bad syntax for the curly brace - Flask Postman

Tags: python, json, http, flask

I have been running through this code and I do not see where the issue is.  This is the json I am submitting via Postman:

```
{
    "username" : "John1",
    "password" : "password",
    "name" : "John Doe",
    "email" : "JDoe@email.com" 
}
```

I have also used the brackets as well like so:

```
[
{
    "username" : "chase1",
    "password" : "Chasecoding1991",
    "name" : "Chase Quinn",
    "email" : "chase@chase.com" 
}
]
```

It has the same issue either way, except with the brackets it shows the bracket as incorrect.

This is my routes code:

```
@cross_origin()
@auth_bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
def auth():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return 'GET REQUEST received'

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = request.get_json()
            hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')
            user = authModel(userid = str(uuid.uuid4()), name=data['name'], username = data['username'], password=hashed_password, email=data['email'])
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return 'successful'
        except:
            return jsonify({'status': '500'})

    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        return 'PATCH REQUEST received'

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        return 'DELETE REQUEST received'
```

I am submitting the POST request via Postman using JSON as the body in the settings.  There have been no headers set up as of yet on either side.  I have no JWT set up as of yet either.  I have also tried this with both http and https within Postman.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!

The entire error excerpt is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2022 08:36:02] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 308 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2022 08:36:02] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('{')
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2022 08:36:02] "None /auth HTTP/0.9" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
```

Comment: What is the _actual error_ you're getting? On which line and with what stack trace?

Comment: I forgot to add the error from the command prompt

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: Are you actually sending `Content-Type: application/json` in your request, and not form-data?

Comment: yes, i checked the header in postman.  Also, the body is Raw type JSON

Comment: I fixed it, adding answer now

Answer (score -1):

I changed the url in postman to:

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/
```

the real error was the 308 redirect.  It showed that the URL was not there.  Once I did that the program worked flawlessly.